# Node js parameterized query for DocumentDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, document-database

Can anyone tell me which node module I have to require to parameterize queries for DocumentDB in Node.js?

I have structured the query very similar to this [Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/announcing-sql-parameterization-in-documentdb/)  example. I am using the documentdb module, but SqlQuerySpec and SqlParametersCollection are not recognised.

```
IQueryable<Book> queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(
                collectionSelfLink,
                new SqlQuerySpec
        {
                    QueryText = "SELECT * FROM books b WHERE (b.Author.Name = @name)", 
                    Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection() 
            { 
                          new SqlParameter("@name", "Herman Melville")
                    }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in Node.js with the SDK [azure-documentdb-node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node):

```
var querySpec = {
    'query': 'SELECT * FROM books b WHERE (b.Author.Name = @name)',

    "parameters": [
        { "name": "@name", "value": 'Herman Melville' }
    ]
}

client.queryDocuments(collectionUrl, querySpec).toArray(function(err, results) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);

    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: I get "Bad request" when trying to do it this way.

Comment: This was my bad, but it was result of the choice used for the example above. Regardless of what your property name is, you want to add the parameter like this "name: '@color', value: 'red'", for example. The key should always be "name".